# JSON Data outputted to screen

Tags: jquery, json

My web site is outputting the JSON data if i don't let the page fully load.

What would be the best way to fix this issue. I'm retrieving the data from a JQuery ajax request

[image]

Comment: Why don't you let the page fully load?

Comment: Can you give us more details? URL?

Comment: not all users let the page fully load so it outputs the failed json to screen. how do i prevent this from occuring.

Comment: Why is this happening? How do you render the response in the normal case?

Comment: If I go to one page and quickly go to another without it letting the current page load then it outputs the JSON

Comment: Try fixing these issues. https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.gopicnic.com%2F

Comment: It is an alert box. Check if error(failure) section of your ajax has an alert(response);

Comment: .fail(function(data) {
      $("#LoadingImage").hide();
      alert('Unknown error ' + data);
     }); should i just remove the alert?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not remove alert!! just remove the appended data from it!!

```
.fail(function(data) { $("#LoadingImage").hide(); alert('Unknown error occured! Please try again'); });
```

User should not see response data in alerts. Alerts are supposed to be user friendly.

Comment: I know the question was already answered but what if I don't want a output/alert what would be the best way to make sure that the user has no interruption and can easily just go to the next page without even if page didn't load with data.

Comment: User should know that he/she has interrupted an incoming response. Alert was added for the same reason. If you don't want an output/alert, just remove the alert(); from fail function.

Comment: I'm just trying to understand the best method to handle this -- since the user is simply moving to the next page without letting it load.. would an alert really be necessary

Comment: If the  next page is an independent page and do not require current page data so an alert is not necessary! Alert is just a way to inform user that something went wrong, get ready for something unexpected! You can remove the alert in your case, it will not effect anything!

Comment: okay thankyou, i was just wondering since you said "do not remove alert" but thanks for the clarification.